# Font Century Gothic and paracol

Tags: fonts

When I use `paracol` to make two columns and use Century Gothic for Greek and English, the text block is not shown right. I don't understand why the text is justified in some part and in other it is not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
%\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Century Gothic}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}

\columnratio{0.2,0.8}
\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{3}

\switchcolumn

Ο 20$^{ος}$ αιώνας είναι σίγουρα η περίοδος κατά την οποία η συνεχής προσπάθεια του Κεφαλαίου να κυριαρχήσει σε ολόκληρη την επιφάνεια του πλανήτη, ολοκληρώθηκε. Στις αρχές του 21ου αιώνα, πλέον, δεν μπορεί κάποιος να εντοπίσει περιοχές του κόσμου όπου οι κεφαλαιοκρατικές σχέσεις παραγωγής να μην είναι κυρίαρχες και να μην έχουν είτε εξαφανίσει, είτε περιθωριοποιήσει, είτε ενσωματώσει λειτουργικά παλιότερους τρόπους παραγωγής.  

\switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `scale` option in your `\includegraphics` with `width=\columnwidth`, this way the image will fit the column and the text won't cross the limit. You can check how this works by changing the column ratio from `\columnratio{0.2,0.8}` to `\columnratio{0.4,0.6}`, for example.

Also the following lines have been added to apply full justification while forbidding hyphenation:

```
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
```

[image: example image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Century Gothic}

\columnratio{0.2,0.8}
\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}

\switchcolumn

Ο 20$^{ος}$ αιώνας είναι σίγουρα η περίοδος κατά την οποία η συνεχής προσπάθεια του Κεφαλαίου να κυριαρχήσει σε ολόκληρη την επιφάνεια του πλανήτη, ολοκληρώθηκε. Στις αρχές του 21ου αιώνα, πλέον, δεν μπορεί κάποιος να εντοπίσει περιοχές του κόσμου όπου οι κεφαλαιοκρατικές σχέσεις παραγωγής να μην είναι κυρίαρχες και να μην έχουν είτε εξαφανίσει, είτε περιθωριοποιήσει, είτε ενσωματώσει λειτουργικά παλιότερους τρόπους παραγωγής.

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes i paste your code but the problem remains. The text it is not fully justified. I can figure out

Comment: @tremopoulostremo Does it appear differently than mine? Is your Tex up to date?

Comment: yes its like yours. Why the body of the text is not justified in both sides, left right? Sorry i am new to latex and my english are bad

Comment: sorry but again: I know about hyphenation and polyglosia, thats the point. I dont want the body text to hyphenate. When i try this without paracol the body of text is ok (hyphenated or no) but when i use paracol the body of the texts looks like this i sent, without hyphanation. When i hyphenate the text and use paracol its ok. But i want to still use paracol and not hyphenate.

Comment: @tremopoulostremo See new edit.

Comment: @tremopoulostremo Just an FYI in case you didn't know: if this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking on √, near the voting buttons.

Comment: actually if you see the gaps between these greek words are not right, elsewhere are narrow elsewhere are wide

Comment: @tremopoulostremo That's what happens when you justify text. Having justification *and* same space between words is literally impossible, because words have different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You get overfull lines because you haven't loaded greek hyphenation patterns, e.g. with polyglossia:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Century Gothic}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Century Gothic}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{paracol}

\columnratio{0.2,0.8}

\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-A}

\switchcolumn

Ο 20$^{ος}$ αιώνας είναι σίγουρα η περίοδος κατά την οποία η συνεχής προσπάθεια του Κεφαλαίου να κυριαρχήσει σε ολόκληρη την επιφάνεια του πλανήτη, ολοκληρώθηκε. Στις αρχές του 21ου αιώνα, πλέον, δεν μπορεί κάποιος να εντοπίσει περιοχές του κόσμου όπου οι κεφαλαιοκρατικές σχέσεις παραγωγής να μην είναι κυρίαρχες και να μην έχουν είτε εξαφανίσει, είτε περιθωριοποιήσει, είτε ενσωματώσει λειτουργικά παλιότερους τρόπους παραγωγής.\par

%\switchcolumn*

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]